# AS3 in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: actionscript-3

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 2, Column 12    1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number.

Name of Dynamic text in Stage : "benzin_txt"

```
benzin_txt.text -= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the text of a textfield requires a string. You're trying to give it a number.

If you want to interpret the value of a TextField as a number and then subtract its contents by 1 then you must first parse the string. Then turn it back into a string.

```
    var origionalText:String = benzin_txt.text;
    var asNumber:Number = parseInt(origionalText);
    asNumber--;
    benzin_txt.text = asNumber.toString();

    //or

    benzin_txt.text = String( int(benzin_txt.text) - 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but my intention subtracts the number 1
For example, 100-1 = 99     Not    10 .

Comment: PS: @AbedHadada... Does the newer `benzin_txt.text = String( int(benzin_txt.text) - 1);` work for you? It would all be easier if you made a **numerical** var like a `Number` or `int` type that's used for your arithmetic calculations then `textfield` just shows resulting numerical value (like `numVar -= 1` and `benzin_txt.text = String(numVar)` )... Also look into `as3 type casting`if you need to know why `.text = String (Number)`..

Comment: @AbedHadada The example I posted subtracts 1 from your textfield (assuming its contents is a parsable number). It does not truncate your text.

Answer (score 1):

Content of a textField is "String" not "Number". So you can't do numeric operations on it. First you have to Convert it to Number or a related type:

```
number = benzin_txt.text as Number;
```

or

```
number = Number(benzin_txt.text);
```

then reconvert it to String so you can use it as text for your textfield:

```
benzin_txt.text = String(number);
```

or

```
benzin_txt.text = number.toString();
```

Simply:

```
benzin_txt.text = String(Number(benzin_txt.text)-1);
```

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. Worked when I chose the embed font :Numerals